# PooledConnectionFactory - The session has already been closed

Tags: apache-camel, jms, activemq-classic, illegalstateexception, spring-camel

I face an exception and see the following getting logged when using the org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory for producing messages to an AMQ Queue -

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The session has already been closed
    at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledSession.safeGetSessionHolder(PooledSession.java:482) ~[activemq-jms-pool-5.14.3.jar:5.14.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledSession.getInternalSession(PooledSession.java:382) ~[activemq-jms-pool-5.14.3.jar:5.14.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledSession.createQueue(PooledSession.java:197) ~[activemq-jms-pool-5.14.3.jar:5.14.3]
```

It also shows up as :

```
Caused by: javax.jms.IllegalStateException: The Session is closed
         at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSession.checkClosed(ActiveMQSession.java:771) ~[activemq-client-5.14.3.jar:5.14.3]
         at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSession.createQueue(ActiveMQSession.java:1329) ~[activemq-client-5.14.3.jar:5.14.3]
         at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledSession.createQueue(PooledSession.java:197) ~[activemq-jms-pool-5.14.3.jar:5.14.3]
```

A few points to note:
The parameter timeBetweenExpirationCheckMillis was added recently to the bean and the exceptions started showing up only after this change.
My code uses the same connection pool for all consumers and producers. 
For AMQ interactions, I also use concurrent consumers in several places.

The beans for the connection and the pool are as follows:

```
<bean id="jmsPooledConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory" init-method="start" destroy-method="stop" >
    <property name="maxConnections" value="40" />
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="smiConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="timeBetweenExpirationCheckMillis" value="300000" />
</bean>

<bean id="smiConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSslConnectionFactory">
    <property name="brokerURL" value="<ssl_protocol_broker>" />
    <property name="userName" value="***********" />
    <property name="password" value="***********" /> 
    <property name="trustStore" value="************"/>
    <property name="trustStorePassword" value="***********" />
    <property name="keyStore" value="***********"/>
    <property name="keyStorePassword" value="***********" />
    <property name="optimizeAcknowledge" value="true" />
    <property name="dispatchAsync" value="true" />
    <property name="alwaysSessionAsync" value="true" />
    <property name="useAsyncSend" value="true" />
    <property name="watchTopicAdvisories" value="false" />
    <property name="prefetchPolicy" ref="prefetchPolicy" />     
</bean>

<bean id="prefetchPolicy" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQPrefetchPolicy">
    <property name="durableTopicPrefetch" value="2000" />
    <property name="topicPrefetch" value="32766" />
    <property name="queuePrefetch" value="0" />
</bean>

**UPDATE 1:**
Active MQ version : 5.14.5
```

Comment: What version of ActiveMQ are you using? And why did you add that new option?

Comment: I am using AMQ version : 5.14.5. I added the new parameter so that unused connections are removed from the clients pool in a timely manner so as to avoid a pile up of connections at the AMQ broker.